# How to iterate a Button in a Table

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-state

My problem is that I have to hide a button into a react table through some conditions but I do not know how to do since I did not understand how react columns work

Here the extract:

```
class Attachments extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {           
            columns: [
                
                {
                    Header: 'Delete',
                    accessor: 'showDeleteButton',
                    Cell: ({ can = this.state.canDelete }) =>
                        ( 
                        < div >
                            {this.state.thisUserCanDelete && can && < button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-flat" style={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }} title="Delete" onClick={() => console.log('Deleted') }><i className="fa fa-trash" /></button>}
                         </div>
                         ),
                    sortable: false
                }
            ],
        };
    }
```

`**thisUserCanDelete**` and `**canDelete**` are present in the state and are arrays of booleans.
The button is always showed even if the arrays are false

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when an *Array*, *Object* or *Class* is created, they are referenced in the memory so they are always `true` even if they are empty. To check this, you can check the array indexes status like `thisUserCanDelete[0]` to access the `boolean` directly.

```js
const dummyArray = [];
console.log(Boolean(dummyArray));  // true

const anotherDummyArray = [false];
console.log(Boolean(anotherDummyArray));  // true
```

If you log the `thisUserCanDelete` and `can`, we can help more.